# Работа с несколькими Activities в Android Espresso

Tags: java, android, test-automation, espresso

Pager и register находятся в `MainActivity`, дальше начинается `RegistrationActivity`. Как мне задействовать сначала `MainActivity`, а потом `RegistrationActivity`?

```
public class RegistrationActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<RegistrationActivity> {

UiDevice mDevice;

public RegistrationActivityTests() {

    super(RegistrationActivity.class);
}
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
    mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
}
@Test
public void testLogin() throws Throwable{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.pager)).perform(swipeLeft());
    }         Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.register)).perform(ViewActions.click());
   Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.email_text)).perform(ViewActions.typeText("q@q.q"));
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.next_button)).perform(ViewActions.click());
}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

А вы добавьте просто к тестам на MainActivity еще 1 тест, где нажимается на элемент register и проверяется, что `RegistrationActivity` стартовало (проверить существование какого-нить специфического для этой активити елемента).
Типа как здесь [LaunchTest.java](https://github.com/hardsky/lucky-calories/blob/master/LuckyCalories/app/src/androidTest/java/com/hardskygames/luckycalories/LaunchTest.java)
 для `afterClickSignUpBtnMovedToSignUpScreen`.
А тесты `RegistrationActivityTests` оставить как есть.
Т.е. по-идее никаких доп манипуляций, чтобы стартовать вторую активити, не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась тем, что я запустил все в MainActivity, а ошибку с множественными совпадениями в иерархии (там проблема с кнопкой register была и множественными совпадениями в иерархии. Я не понял как сделать серез onData и просто переименовал)